# Facebook comments won't accept {$baseurl}

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I have manually installed facebook comments on my adult video script (non adult content), but keep getting an error message below the commentbox:

```
Warning: http://invalid.invalid/video/%7B$video.VID%7D/%7B$video.title%7D is unreachable.
```

I put this in my file:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MYAPPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div style="padding-bottom:10px;"><img src="/templates/frontend/default/images/facebook-comment.gif"></div>
<div class="fb-comments"  data-href="{$baseurl}/video/{$video.VID}/{$video.title}" data-num-posts="20" data-width="990" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

as per instructions on avs forums, but all it does it produce that error.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template (?) tags `{$baseurl}`, `{$video.VID}` and `{$video.title}` doesn't get resolved and used as is in the final HTML used by comments widget resulting in a wrong URL.

You should ensure that your final URL in `data-href` will be correct and not something literally like this `{$baseurl}/video/{$video.VID}/{$video.title}`.

**Update:**
It's really not clear why this should work at all, you doesn't describe anything within your question that will replace `{$baseurl}` with real URL...

If all you want is having comments social plugin for current page you can simply omit `data-href` property:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-num-posts="20" data-width="990" data-colorscheme="dark">/div>
```

But if you need it to appear on other pages you'll need to use URL associated with comments as `data-href`. It should be relatively easy but depends on what language/framework you use to get the correct URL in place...

Comment: yes i know why it is not working, i was trying to find out what code i should be putting inside data-href="" tags?

Comment: @mcreedy, I can't see any reason why this should work?! Your question doesn't say anything about templates, framework you work with or language capable of doing that work, HTML just isn't something that will do the trick.

Comment: omitting data-href is not advisable as it will put the plugin into compatibility mode. I did mention the framework in my initial question, is it adult video script. It uses php with a template system, the template files end in .tpl.

Comment: @mcreedy, Than link to it and it's documentation and/or tag the question with it. Yep, it'll be in compatibility mode. You use something similar to [`getCurrentUrl` from Facebook PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/6bc64892318622a4111550e79def6e08a4b0a977/src/base_facebook.php#L1036)